# Issue with ID Matrix in GLES2

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I have the following code in my C file...

```
static const char gVertexShader[] =
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n"
    "attribute vec4 vid;\n"
    "varying vec4 fragColor;                   \n"
    "attribute vec4 inColor;   \n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "  gl_Position = vid * vPosition;\n"
    "  fragColor = inColor; \n"
    "}\n";

static const char gFragmentShader[] = "precision mediump float;\n"
    "varying vec4 fragColor;                   \n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "  gl_FragColor = fragColor;\n"
    "}\n";
 .....
 GLuint gvPositionHandle;
 GLuint gvColorHandle;
 GLuint gvIDHandle;
 ....
 GLfloat id[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
 ....
 glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
        gTriangleVertices1);
 glVertexAttribPointer(gvColorHandle, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, current1);
 glVertexAttribPointer(gvIDHandle, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, id);
 checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvColorHandle);
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvIDHandle);
 checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

I works fine without the identity matrix....

[image: Before ID]

Then after I add the identity matrix (So I would not expect any change since it is an *ID* matrix) I see the following...

[image: After ID]

So this looks really wrong. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Is this a column major vs. row major issue or something?

**Using mat4 instead of vec4**

So I noticed that I should probably be using mat4 for my transformation so I changed it to the following....

```
static const char gVertexShader[] =
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n"
    "uniform mat4 vid;\n"
    "varying vec4 fragColor;                   \n"
    "attribute vec4 inColor;   \n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "  gl_Position = vid * vPosition ;\n"
    "  fragColor = inColor; \n"
    "}\n";
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(gProgram, "vid");
glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, false, id);
```

Now at first this *appears* to work, however when I change it to something like this...

```
 GLfloat id[] = { 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f};
```

It does not zoom so I have a feeling it is not right yet...

Comment: I think id should be mat4 instead of vec4.

Comment: I am going to publish an update I tried mat4 and it isn't working either. Give me a sec and I will update...

Comment: It's not column major vs row major thing because you use identity matrix. Transpose of identity matrix is equal to itself so it does not matter in this case.

Comment: Ok thanks, any other idea what I am doing wrong? Also do translation matricies have to be Uniform?

Comment: I have been going through your code 10th time maybe, I am not that much experienced but I don't see anything wrong. Translation matrices have to be uniform because you expect those matrices to stay constant for all your objects, so you define them as read-only by using uniforms. Can you also post your position array?

Comment: Here is an older version of my full code... https://github.com/jrgleason/SimpleAndroidGLPiano/blob/master/jni/gl_code.cpp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35511/discussion-between-jackie-and-user2359247)

Comment: The bottom-right element of your matrix should be 1.0 (not 10.0) for a scaling matrix

Comment: You were right when I corrected the scaling matrix everything scaled properly. I will accept your answer if you create it.